# Python fitz module doesn't install on windows 10

Tags: python

Windows 10
Python Version: 3.7.5

I'm currently trying to create a software that takes as input a pdf and uses PyPDF2 to highlight some words. PyPDF2 works perfectly.

The Module fitz which locates the coordinates of the words however cant be installed on my system.
The error log file is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GH5T5-NQ48pJChhrSWwUmMnbCy0tzeIu/view?usp=sharing

I've already upgraded pip to its latest version and the setuptools.
I also tried all the aforementioned on Python 3.8.0 with the same results.

Comment: The message is (somewhat) clear : you need a C/C++ compiler on your machine. Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Please edit your post and paste just the end showing the error, in your post

Comment: It says *    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/*. Did you try installing?

Comment: I installed it and restarted the pc and i have exactly the same error